# Digitally signature on pdf in Ionic 3

Tags: pdf, ionic3, digital-signature

I have created a mobile app in ionic 3, Where some documents (PDF) uploaded and assigned to different-2 users. Every user have their personal login and check these assigned document in his/her panel.
But now the problem is every user have to check the pdf, signed (digitally signature) it and save back. Is there anyone who can help me to integrate this functionality in ionic3.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not getting exact solutions of above issue in the ionic, But I did it on the server side using [FPDI](https://www.setasign.com/products/fpdi/manual/).

First of all I got user signature from signature pad and then merge signature image with the existing pdf.